# Organize storage based on previous orders algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, knapsack-problem

Assumed I got big storage with a lot of products and every shelf in my storage can store maximum k elements. I also got a long list with ordering details (every order can include a variety of different products)

Now I need to write an algorithm that gets order list details as an input and returns the best way to organize my storage.

The algorithm must follow the terms:

1. Splitting my products into shelves (subgroups size k)
2. Products that usually come together sitting on the same shelf

I thought about double hashmap <productName,<productName, counter>> when every product holds a different hashmap that holds all products that came with it and count the number of times that it came with it but I still find it difficult to split it to subgroups size k.
What do you think? Is there a better way algorithm to organize it or maybe a library that doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically hypergraph partitioning (with the connectivity objective and a hard limit on the number of nodes in each part instead of a demand for k approximately balanced parts). This will optimize the average number of shelves needed per order. There are various libraries; [KaHyPar](https://kahypar.org/) is probably the current best.

Comment: Hey! Thank you. For someone new in this field that how do you recommend to approaching this problem?
 I know simple graph but solving problem using

Comment: @almogTovim you could do a simple greedy algorithm. To pick the next shelf: the first item is the one that (of the items remaining) appears in the most orders. To pick each subsequent item on the shelf, aggregate the orders containing some item already on the shelf and pick the item not already on the shelf that appears in the greatest number of those orders.